# How to convert a Perl string to number (integer or float) to satisfy Moose type constraints?

Tags: perl, types, type-conversion, int, moose

I have a Perl variable instantiated from the value retrieved from a webpage. This variable is used to instantiate a Moose object attribute with a type constraint (ex. 'Int' type). This type constraint is failing if I use the variable as-is (`Validation failed for 'Int' with value "2" at constructor...`). I tried explicit-casting (`my $newvar = int($oldvar);`) and sprintf (`my $newvar = sprintf("%d", $oldvar);`) as suggested in [How can I convert a string to a number in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288900). Both of them are not consistent and result in `0` often. I tried suggestions like `abs()` and arithmetic ops(eg. `+`) mentioned in https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html, which again are not reliable in converting values to Moose's' satisfaction. Since I could not get `Int` type constraint to succeed consistently with unpredictable values from webpage, I did not expand my Moose class to other type constraints like `float` or `ArrayRef[Int]` as a `union` constraint. I put a stripped down code below.

*UPDATE:*
When I was trying to reproduce the problem with stripped down code, I found the JSON->decode() is adding double quotes. Equivalent code is below (Note: it works fine with '2' or "2", but when value is '"2"', it fails. I am simply passing the decoded value to Moose class. After I noticed JSON->decode is enclosing values in double quotes even if they already are encoded, I am kind of stuck on guessing how many extra double quotes will come through CGI; of course, properly escaped. I think my task now is to take CGI->param() and strip all the quotes JSON could add to make it a number.

**MyEvent.pm:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyEvent;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

# MyEvent has identifier
has identifier => (
     is => 'rw',
     isa => 'Int',
     predicate => 'has_identifier',
     required => 1
);

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

**MyEventTest.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;
use MyEvent;

use lib '/home/user/tests/mooseTests';


my $id = '"2"'; # <<< Notice the double quoted string inside single quotes

my $myEvt = MyEvent->new("identifier" => $id);

print Dumper $myEvt;
```

This produces:

```
Attribute (identifier) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Int' with value "2" at constructor MyEvent::new (defined at /home/user/tests/mooseTests/MyEvent.pm line 28) line 39
        MyEvent::new('MyEvent', 'identifier', '"2"') called at MyEventTest.pl line 15
```

Comment: Can you share your code? It's hard to track what you are asking without an example.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, My code is too long. I will try to strip it down to reproduce the problem and add it.

Comment: you've got to show what/how you are doing -- I can't reproduce with what you say (a number under quotes works).  If it's moose's validation then t's not even a dozen lines to demo a problem.

Comment: @zdim I created a stand-alone Moose class and test script without CGI. It is working for quoted and unquoted values. Now working on creating a stripped down CGI script to see if that is the difference.

Comment: @zdim and Hunter McMillen, I added a stripped down version of my code. I think JSON->decode() is adding double quotes, which is simulated using '"2"' in my code.

Comment: Re "*JSON->decode() is adding double quotes.*", That's not true

Comment: @ikegami, you are right. I investigated more and found it is actually coming from client side with JSON->stringify(). Now I am in the process of identifying when/why I get additional double quotes. This has been a long detective work. I wish Perl/Moose had a way to use `2, '2', "2", '"2"', \\"2\\" as 'Int' type`. These differences are because of combination of element.val(), JSON->stringify(), Moose (encode / decode of these identifiers making round trips through CGI to client and back few times). As I test more, I am finding the real reasons than initially assumed.

Comment: Re "*I wish Perl/Moose had a way to use ...*", You can create your own coercions. But that's the wrong way around things. You should fix the bad data. If `JSON->stringify()` produces something that decodes to `"2"`, then the value passed to `JSON->stringify` was the three-character string `"2"` (as produced by `'"2"'`) and not a number. If it's suppose to be a number, you should fix the program that uses `JSON->stringify`

Comment: If the program really did mean to pass the three-chraracter string to `JSON->strinfigy`, then you'll need to properly parse it. But since you didn't say any thing about the format in which it's found, there's no way to know how to properly parse it, so we can't answer your question.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for that suggestion. I already looked at that and I need to provide all the conversion code myself. Moose basically calls my coercion code before the constructor is called. I might eventually do that, but I wish something similar to Scalar::Util (looks-like-number) is available to create an Int from all those variations. I could have done it easily if these were only digits, but need to weed out problem cases.

Comment: [A rewording of my earlier comment] Re "*I wish Perl/Moose had a way to use ...*", It does. There's no way it you treat `"2"` by default, but that doesn't mean it can't be told to do it. You can define your own coercions and specify you want the value to be coerced by using `coerce => 1`.

Comment: Re "*Moose basically calls my coercion code before the constructor is called.*", Before assigning the value to the attribute, you mean (whether the value was passed to the constructor or the accessor). How is that a problem? That's actually ideal.

Comment: Re "*I wish something similar to Scalar::Util (looks-like-number) is available to create an Int from all those variations.*", That would be a rather trivial function to write. `sub { my $s = shift; 1 while $s =~ s/^(\\?['"])(.*)\1\z/$2/s; $s }` Again, you are just pilling bad onto bad. You should fix the earlier problem in your code that leads to this situation. You obviously didn't properly parse something earlier in your code. But this is better than using coercion.

Comment: @ikegami, You are right.I traced the code. These identifiers are generated on the server side or input by the user on the webpage. They travel from webpage -> JSON -> Perl CGI (JSON) -> Moose object -> stream -> database and back. I need to figure out where in this chain the original Int (2) is transforming to '2', "2", '"2"', or \\"2\\" and fix there. Any coercion is a band-aid and as you said it is piling bad on bad.Thanks.